# iPhone, AVAudioPlayer and multiplesounds

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer

im new developer and making  my firt iPhone app ,and i want to make button to on/off multiplesounds , example when i press button for multiple sounds after when i play sounds it plays all sound at same time and if its off can play only one sounds, what code is to make ON/OFF multiple sounds play?

*sorry for my bad english*, **Tanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sania,

In order to play multiple sounds at once, Apple recommends using the `.caf` format which is hardware decoded.  Also, you basically just create a new `AVAudioPlayer` object for each sound file instead of re-using the same object in the case where you only want one sound to play at a time.

I won't go into much of the code since there is already a LOT out there if you just search for it... but here are some helpful links to get you started:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

http://www.mobileorchard.com/easy-audio-playback-with-avaudioplayer/

```
// a function I use to play multiple sounds at once
- (void)playOnce:(NSString *)aSound {

// Gets the file system path to the sound to play.
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:aSound ofType:@"caf"];  

// Converts the sound's file path to an NSURL object
NSURL *soundURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];
self.soundFileURL = soundURL;
[soundURL release];

AVAudioPlayer * newAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: soundFileURL error:nil];  
self.theAudio = newAudio; // automatically retain audio and dealloc old file if new file is loaded

[newAudio release]; // release the audio safely

// buffers data and primes to play
[theAudio prepareToPlay];

// set it up and play
[theAudio setNumberOfLoops:0];
[theAudio setVolume: volumeLevel];
[theAudio setDelegate: self];
[theAudio play];

}
```